# App folders on homescreen being removed automatically when a new app is installed

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, htc-desire, home-screen, home-screen-folders

I have HTC Desire 820 running on Android 5.0.1 Lollipop. I have folders with favorite apps on the home screen. But whenever a new app is installed, all those folders disappeared, and the home screen was being set to default.

I cannot rectify this issue and even cannot find out why this is happening. What is the possible cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Nova launcher? If yes, there is an option in launcher settings to disable this and also to lock the home screen from making changes to it

Comment: Not sure what this nova launcher is, is that an app to lock the app bundles??

Comment: [Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) allows you to customise your UI in different ways and allows you to mask your stock UI.  It had many other features which make it attractive for those who wish to alter UI

Comment: Hmm but I think it is not my issue, all my app bundles are being removed when a new app is installed.

Comment: Which launcher app are you using? If you don't know what does that mean, then we will assume that you're using stock launcher. By app bundles, are you referring to folders?

Comment: Yes its just folders created when we club any two apps